# Silverlight fire an event then fire another even a second later

Tags: silverlight

Is there a way to do something like this?

Background:
I have a button click.  When the button is clicked I try to show a "loading" message, run a bunch of code that does some UI work and then dismiss the "loading" message.  It takes anywhere from a few seconds to 20 seconds usually.  At the moment the loading message doesn't show at all and the UI freezes until the code in my button click is done.

I've read about Background Worker and dispatcher, but haven't been able to get it to work.  I'm not sure if it's because the code in the button click calls all sorts of other code (including 3rd party stuff), but I haven't been able to get it to run correctly.  It all still works, but it still freezes the UI and the loading message doesn't appear.

So, I am wondering if there is another way around this.  Is it possible to set it up so that on the button click I only show the loading message and then a second or so later fire another event that executes my long running process?  That way the UI will still freeze for some seconds, but at least it will show a "loading" message.

Comment: Use BackgroundWorker and your problems will all be solved without UI freezing. What problems did you encounter with it? The important trick with BackgroundWorker is you have to use Dispatcher.Invoke() when calling methods on UI elements.

Comment: I am not really sure.  I used BackgroundWorker and Dispatcher and the application worked as it normally did including still freezing the entire application after the button click.  The problem might not even be threading or UI related.  Maybe the process just takes a long time to complete.  I see my CPU goes up to 50% when this happens, which usually does not happen unless something big is happening.

Comment: Sounds like the call to the chart element itself is slow. System.Threading.Timer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you.  A Timer works.  I used System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer to show my loading indicator, start the timer and then execute the long running code.  The app still freezes, but at least the loading indicator shows first.  That's what I wanted for now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) call.

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMyLoadingMessage(); // your code, not sure what it is
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
       CallMyLongRunningCode(); // again, not sure what this is
       HideMyLoadingMessage();
    }
}
```

I don't believe this is the best solution since it is running on the UI thread, but it should do what you are asking.

What is the long running code doing that takes 20 seconds?

Comment: This code runs okay, but it doesn't alleviate the issue.  When I click the OK button it still freezes the entire app until the process completes and my loading indicator doesn't show up either.  The long running code creates a chart from data using a 3rd party library.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that when you described the issue. Is the long running code getting the data for the chart or just building the chart?

Comment: It uses data that has already been retrieved from a database.  Then it builds the chart based on the data.  As far as I can tell it builds the chart from scratch based on the data it has.  However, the code after that I'm not too familiar with, which is why I'm looking at a faster solution to at least show a loading indicator while the screen is frozen.

Comment: What charting component are you using? Visifire?